# SOS Debugging Extensions for Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windbg, uwp

While trying to track down a fatal null pointer language exceptions (c000027b) in a UWP C#/XAML store project with WinDbg, I cannot get to the CLR Exception object because of a missing SOS debugging extention for Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime. I was unable to locate a matching sos.dll. What am I missing?

Note: The app crash is reproducible, but only happens when not debugging. So running the project under the Visual Studio debugger is unfortunately not a solutions in this case.

```
[...]
0:009> dt -a6 000001c37c6587e0 combase!PSTOWED_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION_V2
[0] @ 000001c3`7c6587e0 
---------------------------------------------
0x000001c3`7a8c8348 
   +0x000 Header           : _STOWED_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION_HEADER
   +0x008 ResultCode       : 80004003
   +0x00c ExceptionForm    : 0y01
   +0x00c ThreadId         : 0y000000000000000000100001111100 (0x87c)
   +0x010 ExceptionAddress : 0x00007ffb`e61f24dd Void
   +0x018 StackTraceWordSize : 8
   +0x01c StackTraceWords  : 5
   +0x020 StackTrace       : 0x000001c3`7c658a80 Void
   +0x010 ErrorText        : 0x00007ffb`e61f24dd  "赈???"
   +0x028 NestedExceptionType : 0x314f454c
   +0x030 NestedException  : 0x000001c3`7b2f8348 Void
[...]
0:009> dpS 0x000001c3`7c658a80 L5
 00007ffb`e61d76a7 combase!RoOriginateLanguageException+0x57 [d:\th\com\combase\winrt\error\error.cpp @ 1083]
 00007ffb`af285df7 mscorlib_ni+0x6a5df7
 00007ffb`af232b76 mscorlib_ni+0x652b76
 00007ffb`af232d30 mscorlib_ni+0x652d30
0:009> .formats 0x314f454c
Evaluate expression:
  Hex:     00000000`314f454c
  Decimal: 827278668
  Octal:   0000000000006123642514
  Binary:  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00110001 01001111 01000101 01001100
  Chars:   ....1OEL
  Time:    Wed Mar 20 01:37:48 1996
  Float:   low 3.01619e-009 high 0
  Double:  4.0873e-315
0:009> !sos.dumpccw 0x000001c3`7b2f8348
The call to LoadLibrary(sos) failed, Win32 error 0n2
    "The system cannot find the file specified."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.
0:009> !sos.dumpccw
The call to LoadLibrary(sos) failed, Win32 error 0n2
    "The system cannot find the file specified."
Please check your debugger configuration and/or network access.
0:009> .cordll -ve -u -l
CLRDLL: Unable to get version info for 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0_1.0.23430.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\SOS.dll', Win32 error 0n87
Cannot Automatically load SOS
CLRDLL: Loaded DLL C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0_1.0.23430.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\mscordaccore.dll
CLR DLL status: Loaded DLL C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.0_1.0.23430.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\mscordaccore.dll
0:009> .chain
[...]
Extension DLL chain:
    dbghelp: image 10.0.10586.15, API 10.0.6, built Fri Nov 20 06:55:01 2015
        [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\dbghelp.dll]
    ext: image 10.0.10586.15, API 1.0.0, built Fri Nov 20 06:55:08 2015
        [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\ext.dll]
    exts: image 10.0.10586.15, API 1.0.0, built Fri Nov 20 06:54:07 2015
        [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP\exts.dll]
    uext: image 10.0.10586.15, API 1.0.0, built Fri Nov 20 06:54:02 2015
        [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\winext\uext.dll]
    ntsdexts: image 10.0.10586.15, API 1.0.0, built Fri Nov 20 07:28:14 2015
        [path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Debuggers\x64\WINXP\ntsdexts.dll]
```

Comment: if possible, share the dmp, maybe we can debug it.

Comment: Hi magicandre1981, Thank you for your kind offer! Here is a zipped copy of the dump: [link](http://1drv.ms/1kjOygG)

Comment: ok, I posted a reply.

Comment: ok, I heard that you also emailed Andrew Richards and he gave you the CLRStack. What was the real issue?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you magicandre1981 and Andrew Richards for your help! With the CLRStack provided by Andrew Richards I was able to narrow down the problematic part to a single method. After an initial workaround based on catching a generic exception, further investigation showed that a Uri passed to the BitmapImage constructor BitmapImage(Uri) cannot reliably be retrieved back via the UriSource property.

A person more knowledgeable about the internal caching mechanism of BitmapImage could may be shed some light on this behaviour. If the BitmapImage internal caching comes into operation, accessing BitmapImage.UriSource.OriginalString may apparently raise a null pointer exception, even if BitmapImage(Uri) was used with a valid Uri to construct the BitmapImage object.

My amended serialisation method does no longer access BitmapImage.UriSource.OriginalString, but instead maintains that Uri with an additional private property of the CastImage class. Problem solved.

```
/// <summary>
/// Translates the current instance into a JsonObject.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>The current instance as a JsonObject.</returns>
public JsonObject Serialise()
{
    JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();

    jsonObject.Add("Number", this.number.HasValue ? JsonValue.CreateNumberValue(this.number.Value) : JsonValue.CreateNullValue());
    jsonObject.Add("Category", (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.category)) ? JsonValue.CreateStringValue(this.category) : JsonValue.CreateNullValue());
    jsonObject.Add("Comment", (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.comment)) ? JsonValue.CreateStringValue(this.comment) : JsonValue.CreateNullValue());

    if (this.performer != null)
    {
        jsonObject.Add("Performer", this.performer.Serialise());
    }
    else
    {
        jsonObject.Add("Performer", JsonValue.CreateNullValue());
    }

    if (this.castImages != null)
    {
        jsonObject.Add("CastImages", this.castImages.Serialise());
    }
    else
    {
        jsonObject.Add("CastImages", JsonValue.CreateNullValue());
    }

    jsonObject.Add("CastClip", this.castClip != null ? JsonValue.CreateStringValue(this.castClip.ToString()) : JsonValue.CreateNullValue());


    return jsonObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

many sosdll reside in the .net framework directory

search and load it

```
0:000> .shell
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Admin><.shell waiting 1 second(s) for process>
<.shell process may need input>cd /d c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework
cd /d c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework
cd /d c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework><.shell waiting 1 second(s) for process>
<.shell process may need input>dir /s /b sos*.* 
dir /s /b sos*.* 
dir /s /b sos*.* 
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\SOS.dll
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\SOS.dll
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\SOS.dll

C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework><.shell waiting 1 second(s) for process>
<.shell process may need input>exit
exit
exit
.shell: Process exited
Press ENTER to continue
<.shell waiting 1 second(s) for process>
<.shell process may need input>

0:000> .load C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\SOS.dll
0:000> .chain

Extension DLL chain:
    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\SOS.dll: image 1.1.4322.2032, API 1.0.0, built Thu Jul 15 12:16:07 2004
```

Comment: Hi blabb, Thank you for your response! You describe a method to find the sos.dlls for the full framework versions. That method does not solve this specific issue as the Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime uses a native image of mscorlib.dll, version 4.6.23430.0. For that, I couldn't find a sos.dll anywhere.

Comment: @Harms: me too, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32291110/where-can-i-get-sos-for-windows-10-iot

Answer (score 0):

ok, with the help of the [Windbg Extension PDE.dll](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=dae128bd454cf957&id=DAE128BD454CF957!7152&ithint=folder,zip&authkey=!ALq3LqMcfgs8JoM) from [Andrew Richards](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andrew_richards/), after running  `!PDE.dpx -dse` to shows all Stowed Exceptions (those 0xC000027B exceptions) I see 5 Stowed Exceptions:

```
0:009> !pde.dpx -dse
=========================================================================================
 PDE v10.0 - Copyright 2015 Andrew Richards
=========================================================================================
Start memory scan  : 0x0000007d1b2fc370 ($csp)
End memory scan    : 0x0000007d1b300000 (User Stack Base)

               r12 : 0x000001c37c658c60 :  !dse combase!STOWED_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION_V1
0x0000007d1b2fc528 : 0x000001c37c658c60 :  !dse combase!STOWED_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION_V1
0x0000007d1b2fc930 : 0x000001c37c6587e0 :  !dse combase!STOWED_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION_V1
0x0000007d1b2fc960 : 0x000001c37a8c8348 :  !dse combase!STOWED_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION_V1
0x0000007d1b2fc9c0 : 0x000001c37c6587e0 :  !dse combase!STOWED_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION_V1
0x0000007d1b2fcaa8 : 0x000001c37c658c30 :  !dse combase!STOWED_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION_V1
```

Showing those exceptions only show `E_UNEXPECTED - Unexpected failure` as error:

```
0:009> !PDE.dse 000001c37c658c30
Stowed Exception Array @ 0x000001c37c658c30

Stowed Exception #1 @ 0x000001c378b49948
    0x8000FFFF (FACILITY_NULL - Default): E_UNEXPECTED - Unexpected failure

    Stack    : 0x1c378b48138
        7ffbdb69fec0 Windows_UI_Xaml!FocusProperties::IsFocusable<CDependencyObject>+0x276bd0
        7ffbdb4fc875 Windows_UI_Xaml!CFocusManager::SetFocusedElement+0x31
        7ffbdb5b68eb Windows_UI_Xaml!CTextBlock::OnPointerPressed+0x10b
        7ffbdb285800 Windows_UI_Xaml!CUIElement::OnPointerPressed+0x50
        7ffbdb3efc62 Windows_UI_Xaml!CControlBase::ScriptCallback+0x2b2
        7ffbdb3ef52c Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::OnScriptCallback+0x25c
        7ffbdb3ef0fa Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::OnWindowMessage+0x3a
        7ffbdb3eedfb Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::WindowProc+0x11b
        7ffbe6a01169 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1f9
        7ffbe6a00ee2 user32!DispatchClientMessage+0xa2
        7ffbe6a1098e user32!_fnDWORD+0x3e
        7ffbe6ca88a4 ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue+0x0
        7ffbe6a21f94 user32!NtUserMessageCall+0x14
        7ffbe6a00804 user32!SendMessageWorker+0x144
        7ffbe6a0065b user32!SendMessageW+0xfb
        7ffbdb3a5b82 Windows_UI_Xaml!CEventManager::Raise+0x342
        7ffbdb3a576f Windows_UI_Xaml!CEventManager::RaiseRoutedEvent+0x14f
        7ffbdb1cc49f Windows_UI_Xaml!CInputManager::ProcessPointerInput+0x333
        7ffbdb3c7d1a Windows_UI_Xaml!CInputManager::ProcessInput+0x96
        7ffbdb3c7bc7 Windows_UI_Xaml!CCoreServices::ProcessInput+0x43
        7ffbdb3c7a52 Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpBrowserHost::HandleInputMessage+0x152
        7ffbdb2a0a2e Windows_UI_Xaml!CJupiterControl::HandlePointerMessage+0xb6
        7ffbdb3c77a0 Windows_UI_Xaml!CJupiterControl::HandleWindowMessage+0x244
        7ffbdb3c72cf Windows_UI_Xaml!CJupiterWindow::CoreWindowSubclassProc+0x13f
        7ffbdb3c7169 Windows_UI_Xaml!CJupiterWindow::StaticCoreWindowSubclassProc+0x49
        7ffbe6a01169 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1f9
        7ffbe6a00c97 user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x1a7
        7ffbdc20b4ec Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessMessage+0x43c
        7ffbdc20af1a Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::WaitAndProcessMessages+0xfa
        7ffbdc20ad98 Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessEvents+0xa8
        7ffbdb59d129 Windows_UI_Xaml!CJupiterWindow::RunCoreWindowMessageLoop+0x61
        7ffbdb59cf33 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DXamlCore::RunMessageLoop+0x47
        7ffbe1c79126 twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Run+0x46
        7ffbe1c9e0da twinapi_appcore!MIDL_user_allocate+0xfa
        7ffbe3968fd0 SHCore!??$MakeAndInitialize@VCClosableStreamWrapper@@UIStream@@PEAU2@$$T@Details@WRL@Microsoft@@YAJPEAPEAUIStream@@$$QEAPEAU3@$$QEA$$T@Z+0x1c4
        7ffbe5cf8102 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
        7ffbe6c5c2e4 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34

Stowed Exception #2 @ 0x000001c378b480d8
    0x8000FFFF (FACILITY_NULL - Default): E_UNEXPECTED - Unexpected failure

    Stack    : 0x1c378b468c8
        7ffbdb69fec0 Windows_UI_Xaml!FocusProperties::IsFocusable<CDependencyObject>+0x276bd0
        7ffbdb4fca3b Windows_UI_Xaml!CFocusManager::UpdateFocus+0x17f
        7ffbdb4fc899 Windows_UI_Xaml!CFocusManager::SetFocusedElement+0x55
        7ffbdb887368 Windows_UI_Xaml!FocusManager_SetFocusedElement+0x70
        7ffbdb6a4014 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::SetFocusedElement+0x26b894
        7ffbdb36e9a0 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::Page::OnLoaded+0x120
        7ffbdb36c5e0 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::ClassMemberEventHandler<DirectUI::Page,Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::IPage,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventHandler,IInspectable,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventArgs>::Invoke+0xb0
        7ffbdb386609 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::CRoutedEventSourceBase<DirectUI::IUntypedEventSource,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventHandler,IInspectable,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventArgs>::Raise+0x3e9
        7ffbdb3860f1 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::CRoutedEventSourceBase<DirectUI::IUntypedEventSource,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventHandler,IInspectable,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventArgs>::UntypedRaise+0x91
        7ffbdb3877ad Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::FireEvent+0x65
        7ffbdb3edd15 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DXamlCore::FireEvent+0x205
        7ffbdb3edaef Windows_UI_Xaml!AgCoreCallbacks::FireEvent+0x4f
        7ffbdb3edf3f Windows_UI_Xaml!CCoreServices::CLR_FireEvent+0x16f
        7ffbdb3eddb1 Windows_UI_Xaml!CommonBrowserHost::CLR_FireEvent+0x21
        7ffbdb3efb66 Windows_UI_Xaml!CControlBase::ScriptCallback+0x1b6
        7ffbdb3ef52c Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::OnScriptCallback+0x25c
        7ffbdb3ef0fa Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::OnWindowMessage+0x3a
        7ffbdb3eedfb Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::WindowProc+0x11b
        7ffbe6a01169 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1f9
        7ffbe6a00ee2 user32!DispatchClientMessage+0xa2
        7ffbe6a1098e user32!_fnDWORD+0x3e
        7ffbe6ca88a4 ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue+0x0
        7ffbe6a21f94 user32!NtUserMessageCall+0x14
        7ffbe6a00804 user32!SendMessageWorker+0x144
        7ffbe6a0065b user32!SendMessageW+0xfb
        7ffbdb3a6d44 Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpBrowserHost::SyncScriptCallbackRequest+0x154
        7ffbdb3a6170 Windows_UI_Xaml!CEventManager::RaiseHelper+0x220
        7ffbdb41e529 Windows_UI_Xaml!CEventManager::RaiseLoadedEvent+0x131
        7ffbdb3f59aa Windows_UI_Xaml!CCoreServices::NWDrawTree+0x110a
        7ffbdb3f393a Windows_UI_Xaml!CWindowRenderTarget::Draw+0x15a
        7ffbdb3f032e Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpBrowserHost::OnTick+0x1ee
        7ffbdb3f00a9 Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::Tick+0xa9
        7ffbdb3eff59 Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::OnReentrancyProtectedWindowMessage+0x59
        7ffbdb3eed9e Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::WindowProc+0xbe
        7ffbe6a01169 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1f9
        7ffbe6a00c97 user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x1a7
        7ffbdc20b4ec Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessMessage+0x43c
        7ffbdc20afbe Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::WaitAndProcessMessages+0x19e
        7ffbdc20ad98 Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessEvents+0xa8
        7ffbdb59d129 Windows_UI_Xaml!CJupiterWindow::RunCoreWindowMessageLoop+0x61
        7ffbdb59cf33 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DXamlCore::RunMessageLoop+0x47
        7ffbe1c79126 twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Run+0x46
        7ffbe1c9e0da twinapi_appcore!MIDL_user_allocate+0xfa
        7ffbe3968fd0 SHCore!??$MakeAndInitialize@VCClosableStreamWrapper@@UIStream@@PEAU2@$$T@Details@WRL@Microsoft@@YAJPEAPEAUIStream@@$$QEAPEAU3@$$QEA$$T@Z+0x1c4
        7ffbe5cf8102 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
        7ffbe6c5c2e4 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34

Stowed Exception #3 @ 0x000001c378b46868
    0x8000FFFF (FACILITY_NULL - Default): E_UNEXPECTED - Unexpected failure

    Stack    : 0x1c378b45058
        7ffbdb69fec0 Windows_UI_Xaml!FocusProperties::IsFocusable<CDependencyObject>+0x276bd0
        7ffbdb4fc875 Windows_UI_Xaml!CFocusManager::SetFocusedElement+0x31
        7ffbdb887368 Windows_UI_Xaml!FocusManager_SetFocusedElement+0x70
        7ffbdb6a4014 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::SetFocusedElement+0x26b894
        7ffbdb36e9a0 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::Page::OnLoaded+0x120
        7ffbdb36c5e0 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::ClassMemberEventHandler<DirectUI::Page,Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::IPage,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventHandler,IInspectable,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventArgs>::Invoke+0xb0
        7ffbdb386609 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::CRoutedEventSourceBase<DirectUI::IUntypedEventSource,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventHandler,IInspectable,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventArgs>::Raise+0x3e9
        7ffbdb3860f1 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::CRoutedEventSourceBase<DirectUI::IUntypedEventSource,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventHandler,IInspectable,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventArgs>::UntypedRaise+0x91
        7ffbdb3877ad Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::FireEvent+0x65
        7ffbdb3edd15 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DXamlCore::FireEvent+0x205
        7ffbdb3edaef Windows_UI_Xaml!AgCoreCallbacks::FireEvent+0x4f
        7ffbdb3edf3f Windows_UI_Xaml!CCoreServices::CLR_FireEvent+0x16f
        7ffbdb3eddb1 Windows_UI_Xaml!CommonBrowserHost::CLR_FireEvent+0x21
        7ffbdb3efb66 Windows_UI_Xaml!CControlBase::ScriptCallback+0x1b6
        7ffbdb3ef52c Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::OnScriptCallback+0x25c
        7ffbdb3ef0fa Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::OnWindowMessage+0x3a
        7ffbdb3eedfb Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::WindowProc+0x11b
        7ffbe6a01169 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1f9
        7ffbe6a00ee2 user32!DispatchClientMessage+0xa2
        7ffbe6a1098e user32!_fnDWORD+0x3e
        7ffbe6ca88a4 ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue+0x0
        7ffbe6a21f94 user32!NtUserMessageCall+0x14
        7ffbe6a00804 user32!SendMessageWorker+0x144
        7ffbe6a0065b user32!SendMessageW+0xfb
        7ffbdb3a6d44 Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpBrowserHost::SyncScriptCallbackRequest+0x154
        7ffbdb3a6170 Windows_UI_Xaml!CEventManager::RaiseHelper+0x220
        7ffbdb41e529 Windows_UI_Xaml!CEventManager::RaiseLoadedEvent+0x131
        7ffbdb3f59aa Windows_UI_Xaml!CCoreServices::NWDrawTree+0x110a
        7ffbdb3f393a Windows_UI_Xaml!CWindowRenderTarget::Draw+0x15a
        7ffbdb3f032e Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpBrowserHost::OnTick+0x1ee
        7ffbdb3f00a9 Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::Tick+0xa9
        7ffbdb3eff59 Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::OnReentrancyProtectedWindowMessage+0x59
        7ffbdb3eed9e Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::WindowProc+0xbe
        7ffbe6a01169 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1f9
        7ffbe6a00c97 user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x1a7
        7ffbdc20b4ec Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessMessage+0x43c
        7ffbdc20afbe Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::WaitAndProcessMessages+0x19e
        7ffbdc20ad98 Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessEvents+0xa8
        7ffbdb59d129 Windows_UI_Xaml!CJupiterWindow::RunCoreWindowMessageLoop+0x61
        7ffbdb59cf33 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DXamlCore::RunMessageLoop+0x47
        7ffbe1c79126 twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Run+0x46
        7ffbe1c9e0da twinapi_appcore!MIDL_user_allocate+0xfa
        7ffbe3968fd0 SHCore!??$MakeAndInitialize@VCClosableStreamWrapper@@UIStream@@PEAU2@$$T@Details@WRL@Microsoft@@YAJPEAPEAUIStream@@$$QEAPEAU3@$$QEA$$T@Z+0x1c4
        7ffbe5cf8102 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
        7ffbe6c5c2e4 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34

Stowed Exception #4 @ 0x000001c378773828
    0x8000FFFF (FACILITY_NULL - Default): E_UNEXPECTED - Unexpected failure

    Stack    : 0x1c378772018
        7ffbdb69fec0 Windows_UI_Xaml!FocusProperties::IsFocusable<CDependencyObject>+0x276bd0
        7ffbdb437162 Windows_UI_Xaml!CFocusManager::GetFirstFocusableElement+0x22
        7ffbdb36ecbf Windows_UI_Xaml!FocusManager_GetFirstFocusableElement+0x3f
        7ffbdb36e929 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::Page::OnLoaded+0xa9
        7ffbdb36c5e0 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::ClassMemberEventHandler<DirectUI::Page,Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::IPage,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventHandler,IInspectable,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventArgs>::Invoke+0xb0
        7ffbdb386609 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::CRoutedEventSourceBase<DirectUI::IUntypedEventSource,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventHandler,IInspectable,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventArgs>::Raise+0x3e9
        7ffbdb3860f1 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::CRoutedEventSourceBase<DirectUI::IUntypedEventSource,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventHandler,IInspectable,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventArgs>::UntypedRaise+0x91
        7ffbdb3877ad Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::FireEvent+0x65
        7ffbdb3edd15 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DXamlCore::FireEvent+0x205
        7ffbdb3edaef Windows_UI_Xaml!AgCoreCallbacks::FireEvent+0x4f
        7ffbdb3edf3f Windows_UI_Xaml!CCoreServices::CLR_FireEvent+0x16f
        7ffbdb3eddb1 Windows_UI_Xaml!CommonBrowserHost::CLR_FireEvent+0x21
        7ffbdb3efb66 Windows_UI_Xaml!CControlBase::ScriptCallback+0x1b6
        7ffbdb3ef52c Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::OnScriptCallback+0x25c
        7ffbdb3ef0fa Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::OnWindowMessage+0x3a
        7ffbdb3eedfb Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::WindowProc+0x11b
        7ffbe6a01169 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1f9
        7ffbe6a00ee2 user32!DispatchClientMessage+0xa2
        7ffbe6a1098e user32!_fnDWORD+0x3e
        7ffbe6ca88a4 ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue+0x0
        7ffbe6a21f94 user32!NtUserMessageCall+0x14
        7ffbe6a00804 user32!SendMessageWorker+0x144
        7ffbe6a0065b user32!SendMessageW+0xfb
        7ffbdb3a6d44 Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpBrowserHost::SyncScriptCallbackRequest+0x154
        7ffbdb3a6170 Windows_UI_Xaml!CEventManager::RaiseHelper+0x220
        7ffbdb41e529 Windows_UI_Xaml!CEventManager::RaiseLoadedEvent+0x131
        7ffbdb3f59aa Windows_UI_Xaml!CCoreServices::NWDrawTree+0x110a
        7ffbdb3f393a Windows_UI_Xaml!CWindowRenderTarget::Draw+0x15a
        7ffbdb3f032e Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpBrowserHost::OnTick+0x1ee
        7ffbdb3f00a9 Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::Tick+0xa9
        7ffbdb3eff59 Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::OnReentrancyProtectedWindowMessage+0x59
        7ffbdb3eed9e Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::WindowProc+0xbe
        7ffbe6a01169 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1f9
        7ffbe6a00c97 user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x1a7
        7ffbdc20b4ec Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessMessage+0x43c
        7ffbdc20afbe Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::WaitAndProcessMessages+0x19e
        7ffbdc20ad98 Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessEvents+0xa8
        7ffbdb59d129 Windows_UI_Xaml!CJupiterWindow::RunCoreWindowMessageLoop+0x61
        7ffbdb59cf33 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DXamlCore::RunMessageLoop+0x47
        7ffbe1c79126 twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Run+0x46
        7ffbe1c9e0da twinapi_appcore!MIDL_user_allocate+0xfa
        7ffbe3968fd0 SHCore!??$MakeAndInitialize@VCClosableStreamWrapper@@UIStream@@PEAU2@$$T@Details@WRL@Microsoft@@YAJPEAPEAUIStream@@$$QEAPEAU3@$$QEA$$T@Z+0x1c4
        7ffbe5cf8102 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
        7ffbe6c5c2e4 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34

Stowed Exception #5 @ 0x000001c378b4b1b8
    0x8000FFFF (FACILITY_NULL - Default): E_UNEXPECTED - Unexpected failure

    Stack    : 0x1c378b499a8
        7ffbdb69fec0 Windows_UI_Xaml!FocusProperties::IsFocusable<CDependencyObject>+0x276bd0
        7ffbdb436aa8 Windows_UI_Xaml!CFocusManager::GetFirstFocusableElementInternal+0x190
        7ffbdb436a31 Windows_UI_Xaml!CFocusManager::GetFirstFocusableElementInternal+0x119
        7ffbdb436a31 Windows_UI_Xaml!CFocusManager::GetFirstFocusableElementInternal+0x119
        7ffbdb436a31 Windows_UI_Xaml!CFocusManager::GetFirstFocusableElementInternal+0x119
        7ffbdb436a31 Windows_UI_Xaml!CFocusManager::GetFirstFocusableElementInternal+0x119
        7ffbdb437152 Windows_UI_Xaml!CFocusManager::GetFirstFocusableElement+0x12
        7ffbdb36ecbf Windows_UI_Xaml!FocusManager_GetFirstFocusableElement+0x3f
        7ffbdb36e929 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::Page::OnLoaded+0xa9
        7ffbdb36c5e0 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::ClassMemberEventHandler<DirectUI::Page,Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::IPage,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventHandler,IInspectable,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventArgs>::Invoke+0xb0
        7ffbdb386609 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::CRoutedEventSourceBase<DirectUI::IUntypedEventSource,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventHandler,IInspectable,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventArgs>::Raise+0x3e9
        7ffbdb3860f1 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::CRoutedEventSourceBase<DirectUI::IUntypedEventSource,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventHandler,IInspectable,Windows::UI::Xaml::IRoutedEventArgs>::UntypedRaise+0x91
        7ffbdb3877ad Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DependencyObject::FireEvent+0x65
        7ffbdb3edd15 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DXamlCore::FireEvent+0x205
        7ffbdb3edaef Windows_UI_Xaml!AgCoreCallbacks::FireEvent+0x4f
        7ffbdb3edf3f Windows_UI_Xaml!CCoreServices::CLR_FireEvent+0x16f
        7ffbdb3eddb1 Windows_UI_Xaml!CommonBrowserHost::CLR_FireEvent+0x21
        7ffbdb3efb66 Windows_UI_Xaml!CControlBase::ScriptCallback+0x1b6
        7ffbdb3ef52c Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::OnScriptCallback+0x25c
        7ffbdb3ef0fa Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::OnWindowMessage+0x3a
        7ffbdb3eedfb Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::WindowProc+0x11b
        7ffbe6a01169 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1f9
        7ffbe6a00ee2 user32!DispatchClientMessage+0xa2
        7ffbe6a1098e user32!_fnDWORD+0x3e
        7ffbe6ca88a4 ntdll!KiUserCallbackDispatcherContinue+0x0
        7ffbe6a21f94 user32!NtUserMessageCall+0x14
        7ffbe6a00804 user32!SendMessageWorker+0x144
        7ffbe6a0065b user32!SendMessageW+0xfb
        7ffbdb3a6d44 Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpBrowserHost::SyncScriptCallbackRequest+0x154
        7ffbdb3a6170 Windows_UI_Xaml!CEventManager::RaiseHelper+0x220
        7ffbdb41e529 Windows_UI_Xaml!CEventManager::RaiseLoadedEvent+0x131
        7ffbdb3f59aa Windows_UI_Xaml!CCoreServices::NWDrawTree+0x110a
        7ffbdb3f393a Windows_UI_Xaml!CWindowRenderTarget::Draw+0x15a
        7ffbdb3f032e Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpBrowserHost::OnTick+0x1ee
        7ffbdb3f00a9 Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::Tick+0xa9
        7ffbdb3eff59 Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::OnReentrancyProtectedWindowMessage+0x59
        7ffbdb3eed9e Windows_UI_Xaml!CXcpDispatcher::WindowProc+0xbe
        7ffbe6a01169 user32!UserCallWinProcCheckWow+0x1f9
        7ffbe6a00c97 user32!DispatchMessageWorker+0x1a7
        7ffbdc20b4ec Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessMessage+0x43c
        7ffbdc20afbe Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::WaitAndProcessMessages+0x19e
        7ffbdc20ad98 Windows_UI!Windows::UI::Core::CDispatcher::ProcessEvents+0xa8
        7ffbdb59d129 Windows_UI_Xaml!CJupiterWindow::RunCoreWindowMessageLoop+0x61
        7ffbdb59cf33 Windows_UI_Xaml!DirectUI::DXamlCore::RunMessageLoop+0x47
        7ffbe1c79126 twinapi_appcore!Windows::ApplicationModel::Core::CoreApplicationView::Run+0x46
        7ffbe1c9e0da twinapi_appcore!MIDL_user_allocate+0xfa
        7ffbe3968fd0 SHCore!??$MakeAndInitialize@VCClosableStreamWrapper@@UIStream@@PEAU2@$$T@Details@WRL@Microsoft@@YAJPEAPEAUIStream@@$$QEAPEAU3@$$QEA$$T@Z+0x1c4
        7ffbe5cf8102 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x22
        7ffbe6c5c2e4 ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x34
```

I'll ask him after the christmas holiday if his Team saw such crash dumps before.

Comment: Maybe you want to delete the Christmas sentence?

Comment: The link to the dll seems to be down.

Comment: @testing try this link: https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=!AJeSzeiu8SQ7T4w&id=DAE128BD454CF957!7152&cid=DAE128BD454CF957 and get the **PDE v10.zip**