# Inspect dump files from UWP app

Tags: c#, debugging, win-universal-app, windows-10-mobile, crash-dumps

First I enabled saving of dump files on a Windows 10 Mobile phone:

> Settings > Update & Security > For developers > Save this many crash dumps: 3

Then I debugged an app which throwed an exception. I continued the debugging after stop. After disconnecting and connecting the mobile phone again, I was able to access the dump file stored under `Windows phone\Phone\Documents\Debug` directory. The file is called

`FPCL.WIndows - a736c773-c105-4b30-a799-4bf317872f5e with exception C000027B on 5-03-2016 12.11.dmp`

and has about 140 MB!

I copied the file to the `bin` directory of my UWP app. Afterwards I opened it as file in Visual Studio 2015 (in the same project). Now I can see the *Dump Summary* and I have the following buttons:

- Debug with Managed Only
- Debug with Mixed
- Debug with Native Only
- Set symbol paths
- Copy all to clipboard

---

If I run *Debug with Managed Only* I get

> A fatal exception was caught by the runtime. See $stowedexception in the Watch window to view the original exception information.

and on clicking *Break* I get

> No compatible code running. The selected debug engine does not support any code executing on the current thread (e.g. only native runtime code is executing).

In the *Watch 1* window I see the following

> Name: {CLR}$stowedexception
>   Value: {"The method or operation is not implemented."}
>   Type: System.NotImplementedException

This should be the exception I have thrown in my app. When I open this node and look under *StackTrace* I can get a line number. On pressing *Continue* I get

> The debugger cannot continue running the process. This operation is not supported when debugging dump files.

So I can only stop it.

---

If I run *Debug with Mixed* I get again

> A fatal exception was caught by the runtime. See $stowedexception in the Watch window to view the original exception information.

and on clicking *Break* I get

> kernelbase.pdb not loaded
>   kernelbase.pdb contains the debug information required to find the source for the module KERNELBASE.dll
>   Module Information: Version: 10.0.10586.218 (th2_release.160401-1800) Original Location: KERNELBASE.dll
>   Try one of the following options: Change existing PDB and binary search paths and retry: Microsoft Symbol Servers

Here I can either press *Load* or *New*. So the kernelbase.pdb isn't found under the given location. Should it exists? Where should I find it?

In the *Watch 1* window I see the same as above and I can only stop it.

---

If I run *Debug with Native Only* I get

> Unhandled exception at 0x76ECDF95 (combase.dll) in FPCL.WIndows - f736c883-f105-4d30-a719-4bf328872f5e with exception C000027B on 5-03-2016 12.11.dmp: 0xC000027B: Anwendungsinterne Ausnahme (parameters: 0x075C6838, 0x00000002).

and on clicking *Break* I get the same missing kernelbase error as above, but here in the *Watch 1* window the *Value* is `Unable to evaluate the expression`. So I can only stop it.

---

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4699467/426227) I should be able to inspect the source code and find the cause. But how is such a UWP dump file inspected correctly?

Comment: i have had some success with `stowed exceptions` using [windbg](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/hardware/ff551063(v=vs.85).aspx) You will need to use some commands to get to the meat of the exception I will try and dig them out and post in an answer later

Comment: use Windbg to analyze the dump: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34470061/1466046

Comment: @SWilko follow my link. The extension is nice to show the stowed exceptions easy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention

> [...] 0xC000027B [...]
>
> [...] $stowedexception [...]

which are both indicators that there is a Stowed Exception inside the dump.

To analyze such exceptions, first watch [Channel 9 Defrag Tools, episode 136](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/DefragTools-136-Debugging-User-Mode-Crash-Dumps-Part-2) where Andrew Richards explains and then analyzes them (at [3:28](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/DefragTools-136-Debugging-User-Mode-Crash-Dumps-Part-2#time=03m28s)).
Then download the PDE extension from the [Defrag Tools OnDrive](https://onedrive.live.com/?authkey=!AJeSzeiu8SQ7T4w&id=DAE128BD454CF957!7152&cid=DAE128BD454CF957) and analyze your dump in [windbg](/questions/tagged/windbg) instead of Visual Studio.

Regarding the symbols of `kernelbase`, they should be downloaded from the Microsoft symbol server. To set that up in WinDbg, use `.symfix;.reload`. If you want to give it another try in Visual Studio, go to Debug / Options and choose Debugging / Symbols, then check "Microsoft Symbol Servers".

Regarding the button to press in Visual Studio, choose "Managed only" when debugging the debug build, because your app will run on CoreCLR and choose "Native Only" when debugging the release build, because your app will use .NET native runtime support. (This applies if you didn't change the default settings; otherwise choose according to your compilation settings)