# Stowed Exceptions - Background Task - UWP C#

Tags: c#, exception, uwp, windows-10-universal, background-task

I created a Background task in my UWP project, and the Dev Center of Microsoft store catch many exception inside Background task:

- `STOWED_EXCEPTION_System.Exception;`
- `STOWED_EXCEPTION_System.ArgumentException;`
- `STOWED_EXCEPTION_System.Exception;`

When I run my application in Debug mode on Visual Studio, never cath any exception :(

Someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37002752/inspect-dump-files-from-uwp-app

Answer (score 1):

I didn't faced such an error while developing Window App.

So, The only suggestion to Use the Application.UnhandledException event to handle exception that you have not handled via try/catch to prevent the app from crashing.

You may also need to handle errors at application level. See below link for more detail.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2014/10/16/strategies-for-handling-errors-in-your-windows-store-apps/