# Windows 8.1 app packages created on windows 10 OS doesn't work on windows 8.1 OS

Tags: windows, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-10

I'm using VS 2015 under Windows 10 OS and building a Windows 8.1 store app. When publishing my app I use x86 and x64 architecture packages and after the package has been installed using powershell on Windows 10 OS(Build 10240) it works fine but when I try to install it on Windows 8.1 app crashes before it starts.

I build and publish the the app on VS 2013 under Windows 8.1 OS and the app works fine on both 8.1 and 10 OS's.

Is there a problem with Windows 10(Build 10240)? If yes which OS build did they fixed this issue?

Please advice.

Comment: capture a crash dump on the Win8.1 system (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513638(VS.85).aspx) and analyze the dmp with windbg (http://stackoverflow.com/a/34470061/1466046) to see why the app crashes

Comment: Can you find some useful info about the crash in event viewer?

Comment: Nop it just says app crashes. No useful information is provided on the logs.

Comment: have you captured a dump and analyzed it?

Comment: Hi, it doesn't provide much information, just mention app crashes. That's it.

Comment: use the PDE.dll in Windbg to get more details. Follow the SO link I added to my comment

Comment: have you tried !pde.dpx -dse to list all exceptions and look at the exceptions?

Comment: any updates? have you now tried it or not?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, sorry I was busy past couple of weeks, I'll try this on tomorrow and let you know for sure. Thanks again.