# UWP application crashes few seconds after launching

Tags: windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

My UWP application crashes immediately after launching. 
On some devices it says

> faulting module twinapi.appcore.dll

and on others it says

> faulting module windows.ui.xaml.dll

Any idea what causes this?

Comment: You need to provide some more information. Does it happen in Deubg or Release, is it an empty blank app or you have something inside, any code that can particulary cause exception?

Comment: It is not a blank app. This happens when I sideload the app to other machines.

Comment: What Visual Studio service pack version do you have? Have you tried to recover or update Visual Studio?

Comment: create a dmp and analyze the dmp with Windbg(PDE.DLL): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454704/windows-8-1-app-packages-created-on-windows-10-os-doesnt-work-on-windows-8-1-os#comment62447497_37454704

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it resolved. I had to use group policy to configure the devices for sideloading apps. Enabling "Allow all trusted apps to install" solved the issue.

Comment: Please mark it as answered even if it was solved by you.